# Is there a way to search an array for a value in the array in its string form?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have an array in which I am trying to ask the user a question, have them give their answer (and in their answer will be a string value in the array), and then use their answer to formulate a response to them. I tried using .equals and changing the array into a list. Right now I am using a boolean to find if the string from the array is present in the user's answer or not, but I want the code to be very flexible (which means I want it not to matter if the user says "Hi" or "hi". Here's the code below:

```
    String[] albums = {"positions", "thank u, next", "sweetener", "k bye for now", 
    "dangerous woman", "my everything", "yours truly"};
    String firstQuestion = ari.nextLine();
    boolean isFound0 = firstQuestion.contains(albums[0]);
            if (isFound0) {
                System.out.println("tysm! i love " + (albums[0]) + " as well!");
            }
```

Comment: You want to use a Map, not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can go over the albums array with an [foreach-loop](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/for-each-loop-in-java/) and if "firstQuestion " is matched you set "isFound0" to true and break out of the loop with break; to improve the string matching you can either use a library or do some quick and dirty operations on **both** strings before comparing them to reduce false negatives.

firstQuestion.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", ""); // makes all letters lowercase and removes all characters that aren't letters